# Is there any API for getting Slack user's or channel's email when provided user's email or channel's name?

Tags: slack, slack-api, slack-commands

Context: Slack provides you with the option to send emails directly as DM or in a channel. One can get this email address in user's or channel's integration tab and then opening ***Send emails to this conversation*** pop-up.

[image: channel's options]

[image: create email address]

Here, I'm looking for such API which take slack user's email address(e.g. john@meta.com) or a channel's tag(e.g. #tech-discussion) as parameter and respond with slack integrated email address(e.g. z-test-alert-aaaai2f5zktgpqhhwn74dh5czq@meta.slack.com)

Answer (score 0):

The Slack channel integrated email is not Slack's functionality but provided by Email Slack App, then I don't think Slack api can provide this information.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34582580)